# Remove vertex mid of edge, Function like Cinema 4d's Optimize

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Does Blender has the function like C4D's optimize: can remove isolated vertexes or some problem vertexes in picture below. They are in mid of the edge, I can not use merge by distance function.. What should i do except manual selecting them..

[image: Need to remove these vertexes in mid of an edge]

Comment: limited dissolve https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html

Comment: Since the loose vertices are every other vertex in this scenario, you could also select the whole edge ring and then use `select > checker deselect` (change the offset if necessary) to select all the loose ones.

Comment: @susu Thank you so much , I tried that, solved my problem !

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you for your reply! I also tried 'Checker Deselect' , it will select all vertexes from those edges..

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-remove-loose-vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Limited dissolve**

> Mode: Edit Mode

> Menu: Mesh ‣ Delete ‣ Limited Dissolve

> This tool can simplify your mesh by dissolving vertices and edges separating flat regions.

> Max Angle

> Reduces detail on planar faces and linear edges with an adjustable angle threshold.

> All Boundaries

> Always dissolve vertices that have two edge users at boundaries.

> Delimit

> Prevent faces from joining when they don’t share certain properties (material for e.g.).

From:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html